# Workaround or solution needed on how to perform a Symfony Repository call with two selects, whereby the second gets cast to an object?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository

I am trying to perform a left outer join for objects called `Data`, by putting a condition (status = 3) on the join table `JoinData` and then left joining the `Data`.

```
class JoinDataRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getDataWithStatusEqualsThree()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('jd')
               ->select('jd','d')
               ->where('jd.status = 3')
               ->leftJoin('jd.data', 'd')
               ->addOrderBy('d.created', 'DESC');

        return $qb->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
    }
}
```

The result looks like this - having attributes of the two objects selected 1) the `JoinData` and 2) the `Data` attributes (which i actually would like to have as object):

```
SELECT 
  n0_.status AS status0
  ...
  n1.attribute AS attribute0
  ...
FROM 
  ngl2_join_data n0_ 
  LEFT JOIN ngl2_data n1_ ON n0_.data_id = n1_.id 
WHERE 
  n0_.status = 2 
ORDER BY 
  n1_.created DESC
```

The method returns a list of `JoinData` objects. Is it possible to return just `Data` objects? Or is there a workaround just using the QueryManager...?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
class JoinDataRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getDataWithStatusEqualsThree()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('jd')
               ->select('d')
               ->where('jd.status = 3')
               ->leftJoin('jd.data', 'd')
               ->addOrderBy('d.created', 'DESC');

        return $qb->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will always try to return a list of "JoinData" objects. And since here only attributes from 'd' (data) are returned it complains about not being able to hydrate due to missing attributes.